# Can't get events from emits in my composable

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

I'm trying to generate a confirmation modal when calling my composable, my component instance is mounting well, but I can't access the emits via the : `onCancel`

The goal is to call the dialer every time I need to interact with a confirmation

useModalConfirm.ts

```js
 function confirm(props: ModalConfirmProps) {
        const container = document.createElement('div');
        document.body.appendChild(container);
        const component = createVNode(ModalConfirm, {
            ...props,

            // not working here :(
            onCancel: () => {
                console.log('canceled')
            }
        });
        render(component, container);
        return component.component;
    }
```

ModalConfirm.vue

```js
<script lang="ts" setup>
import {NButton} from "naive-ui";

const emits = defineEmits(["onConfirm", "onCancel"]);

export type ModalConfirmProps = {
  title: string;
  message: string;
  confirmButtonText: string,
  cancelButtonText: string,
};

const props = defineProps<ModalConfirmProps>();
const confirm = () => {

  emits("onConfirm");
};

const cancel = () => {
  emits("onCancel");
};


</script>

<template>
  <div class="ModalConfirm">
    <div class="ModalConfirmContent">
      {{ props.title }}
      {{ props.message }}

      <NButton @click="cancel" type="error">{{ props.cancelButtonText }}</NButton>
      <NButton @click="confirm" type="success">{{ props.confirmButtonText }}</NButton>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

any ideas ?

Comment: Don't start event name with "on", this would translate to onOnCancel prop.

Comment: Where are you calling your composable?

Comment: Do you know that You can use `<Teleport>` component to send component directly to body?

Comment: Thanks @EstusFlask  that was the mistake! I removed the both 'on' on my emits declaration and adjust all emits call and it worked !

Comment: @Mises yes, but i wanna call the component from my composable

Comment: You can still do that, it's only the markup that gets sent